# DataDirect Mongo JDBC Driver- invalid transaction state: read-only SQL-transaction

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc, transactions

Trying out accessing mongodb through DataDirect Mongo JDBC driver (trial version) configuration in WildFly 8 environment. After successful setup read of collection are working fine as expected, but while trying out transaction queries, am getting the exception `invalid transaction state: read-only SQL-transaction`

https://www.progress.com/jdbc/mongodb

EJB 3, SQL Connection : `con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);`

Query : `Insert into test.products values(?,?)`

User Role:

```
{
"_id" : "test.testuser",
"user" : "testuser",
"db" : "test",
"roles" : [ 
    {
        "role" : "readWrite",
        "db" : "test"
    }, 
    {
        "role" : "dbAdmin",
        "db" : "test"
    }
]
}
```

Datasource:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/mongods" pool-name="mongods" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:datadirect:mongodb://localhost:27017;schemaDefinition=E:\Research\Mongodb\schemamap\Test</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodb.MongoDBDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>mongodb</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>testuser</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>36000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>36000</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    <query-timeout>36000</query-timeout>
                    <use-try-lock>36000</use-try-lock>
                    <allocation-retry>36000</allocation-retry>
                    <allocation-retry-wait-millis>36000</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

Exception:

```
2017-05-29 12:23:37,644 SEVERE [com.jee.sample.rest.NewSessionBean] (default task-5) null: java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][MongoDB JDBC Driver][MongoDB]invalid transaction state: read-only SQL-transaction
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.ddcl.b(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.ddcl.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.ddck.b(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.ddck.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbcloud.ddq.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbcloud.ddu.d(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbcloud.ddu.g(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.dddc.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.dddt.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.ddez.b(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.dddt.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.ddt.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.BaseConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.jdbc.mongodbbase.BaseConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:745)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:731)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:405)
at com.jee.sample.rest.NewSessionBean.setMongo(NewSessionBean.java:112) [DynamicQueueListener-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at com.jee.sample.rest.NewSessionBean$$$view7.setMongo(Unknown Source) [DynamicQueueListener-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: com.ddtek.mongodbcloud.sql.ddai: invalid transaction state: read-only SQL-transaction
at com.ddtek.mongodbcloud.sql.error.dda.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
at com.ddtek.mongodbcloud.sql.ddbm.a(Unknown Source) [mongodb.jar:]
... 121 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

to your repository file while executing SQL query. It should work fine.

Comment: my application build on ejb 3 how can use the Transacitonal isolation level

Comment: Sahil Gupa i have isolation level in connection, con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);